# Sprite sheet creating a window of the image surface

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, sprite-sheet

I'm trying to recreate the chrome no internet dino game inside `pygame`/`python`. But whenever I run it it instead of creating the main file window it creates the image window from the sprite sheet file. Don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

main file:

```
# importing the other file where the spritesheet class is
from SpriteSheet import SpriteSheet

import pygame

pygame.init()

SW = 500
SH = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((SW, SH))
SPRITE_SHEET = pygame.image.load('sheet.png')

# mainloop
run = True
while run:

# checking for clicking the x button
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

# cropping the image from the spritesheet
        spritesheet = SpriteSheet(SPRITE_SHEET)
        image = spritesheet.get_image(
            848, 2, 44, 47, (255, 255, 255))
        win.blit(image, (0, 0))
```

sprite sheet file:

```
import pygame

# creating the class
class SpriteSheet(object):
    SpriteSheet = None

# getting the spritesheet
    def __init__(self, sheet):
        self.SpriteSheet = sheet

# cropping the image
    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        image = pygame.display.set_mode([width, height])

        image.blit(self.SpriteSheet, (0, 0), (x, y, width, height))

        image.set_colorkey(color)

        return image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> instead of creating the main file window it creates the image window

No. There is nothing like a image window.

The content of the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object which is associated to the display is what you see in the window.

> ```py
> win = pygame.display.set_mode((SW, SH))
> ```

First you *blit* `SPRITESHEET` on `image` (in `SpriteSheet.get_image()`)

> ```py
> image.blit(self.SpriteSheet, (0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
> ```

Now the content of `image` is the `SPRITESHEET`. Then you *blit* `image` on `win`

> ```py
> win.blit(image, (0, 0))
> ```

Hence the content of `image` (which is the same as `SPRITESHEET`) is displayed.

When you don't want to see the content of `SPRITESHEET` in the window, then you have to remove the line

<s>`>win.blit(image, (0, 0))`</s>

---

By the way, pygame wiki provides a nice and complete [Spritesheet](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/Spritesheet) example.